# Xamarin forms custom renderer for iOS radio button

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create a radio button custom renderer for iOS but could not find a RadioButtonRenderer in the iOS project. Does anyone know how can we override the radio button control?

Basically, I want to change the radio button background colour without affecting the selected button colour.

My radio button on iOS looks like the below when the system default theme is dark mode and you override the theme to be light mode.

[image]

If I change the above background colour to white, then the selected icon is not visible.

Android looks fine as below.

[image]

Is there any iOS equivalent of below Android renderer code?

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using StorefrontRetail.Custom;
using StorefrontRetail.Droid.Custom;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedRadioButton), typeof(ExtendedRadioButtonRenderer))]

namespace StorefrontRetail.Droid.Custom
{
    public class ExtendedRadioButtonRenderer : RadioButtonRenderer
    {
        public ExtendedRadioButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<RadioButton> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                ExtendedRadioButton extendedRadioButton = (ExtendedRadioButton) e.NewElement;
                Control.ButtonTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(extendedRadioButton.ButtonColor.ToAndroid());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27b6842e-02e8-48fc-b1bf-9bb2f7a7df6a/radiobuttonrenderer-for-ios?forum=xamarinforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your radiobutton with **Control Template**, it allows you to set the UI as what you  want,code like:

```
   <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <Color x:Key="LightRadioButtonColor">#F3F2F1</Color>
            <Color x:Key="DarkRadioButtonColor">#9B9A99</Color>

            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ThemeRadioTemplate">
                <Frame
                    Padding="0"
                    BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource DarkRadioButtonColor},
                                                      Light={StaticResource LightRadioButtonColor}}"
                    BorderColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource DarkRadioButtonColor},
                                                  Light={StaticResource LightRadioButtonColor}}"
                    HasShadow="False"
                    HeightRequest="80"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    WidthRequest="80">
                    <Grid Margin="4" WidthRequest="80">
                        <Grid
                            HeightRequest="20"
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                            WidthRequest="20">
                            <Ellipse
                                Fill="White"
                                HeightRequest="18"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Stroke="#2E2545"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                WidthRequest="18" />
                            <Ellipse
                                x:Name="Check"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                Fill="#df6e57"
                                HeightRequest="10"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Stroke="#df6e57"
                                StrokeThickness="0"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                WidthRequest="10" />
                        </Grid>
                        <!-- This enables us to put in dynamic content -->
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroupList>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#df6e57" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="Check" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#F3F2F1" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="Check" Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateGroupList>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Frame>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*" ColumnSpacing="10">
    <RadioButton ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ThemeRadioTemplate}" Content="Default" IsChecked="True" />
    <RadioButton ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ThemeRadioTemplate}" Grid.Column="1" Content="Light" />
    <RadioButton ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ThemeRadioTemplate}" Grid.Column="2" Content="Dark" />
</Grid>
```